# Add column across multiple files

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I have a folder of 90 excel files each named according to the date of the data within and where the single worksheet in each file has the exact same name. I need to combine the worksheets into a single worksheet, which I can easily do, but I need to differentiate among the data from the various sheets

Workbook1 named **12-2015.xlsx**
Worksheet named **Detail**

```
Cust_ID Net_Sales  
1023 $80  
1027 $150
```

Workbook2 named **01-2016.xlsx**
Worksheet named **Detail**

```
Cust_ID Net_Sales  
1023 $100  
1027 $175
```

I need all the data combined on one sheet along with the date of the date (the Workbook name)

Comment: If you are doing this using VBA, just capture the Name property of the Workbook object and output that along with your column.

Comment: Are you expecting us to write the script for you? If not, please share what you've tried so we can see where it's going wrong

Answer (score 0):

1. This formula will generate the name of the Workbook:

   =MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("[",CELL("filename",A1))+1,FIND("]", CELL("filename",A1))-FIND("[",CELL("filename",A1))-1)
2. Of course, that formula will always update when you move it to the new workbook, so to prevent that, the formula must never be pasted as a formula; it must be pasted as 'values only'. You can do so by copying it and right-click and select "paste as" -> 'values only'

I hope this helps